# How do I check the connection status of my WCF service

Tags: winforms, wcf

I am currently developing a WCF publish subscribe service on a winform app. How do I code it in such a way that whenever a client subscribes to my service, I would be able to display a message in my textbox saying, "1 client has connected/disconnected to/from the service"

Comment: WCF services aren't like ADO.NET connections - you don't "connect to it" and stay connected. Basically, each call is a fresh new call - each call by default (and by best practice) gets a new service instance, that request gets handled, result returned, and then the service gets disbanded again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As marc said, clients don't maintain connections to WCF services, but you can monitor imaginary connections by having the clients regularly call an "I'm here" method on the service while they are "connected", and when they stop calling it, you consider them to be "disconnected". I've found this strategy to work well for a distributed processing application when I wanted to keep track of how many agents were available to do work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Microsoft Duplex Services (WCF)

[Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx)